# How to get indexpath of selected row on longgesture press in UITableView in xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am working on xamarin.ios. I created a UITableView and bind some data in it. Now I want to use LongPressGesture on UITableViewCell of the table. I open a popup on LongPressGesture and want to show data related with selected row. But I am not getting how to get index path of selected row on LongPress. 
Please update how I can get the indexpath value on longpress gesture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the UILongPressGestureRecognizer to the TableView then use this code as your action.

```
void HandleLongPress (UILongPressGestureRecognizer longPressGesture)
{
    var point = longPressGesture.LocationInView (yourTableView);

    var indexPath = yourTableView.IndexPathForRowAtPoint (point);

    if (indexPath == null)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine ("Long press on table view, not row.");
    }
    else if (longPressGesture.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine ($"Long press on row, at {indexPath.Row}");
    }
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Add following method in .xaml.cs file and you'll get indexPath of selected row on long press selection

public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    UIAlertController okAlertController = UIAlertController.Create ("Row Selected", tableItems[indexPath.Row], UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
    okAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
    ...

```
tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
```

}